# Разница java объектов: применение изменений

Tags: java, объекты, graph

Данный вопрос уже был мною задан на английской версии сайта [Java object diffs: How to apply diffs to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249178/java-object-diffs-how-to-apply-diffs-to-an-object).

Суть проблемы такая:

Есть объект A' - большой и тяжелый, внутри листы, мапы, листы мапов, сеты и прочие сущности.

В какой-то момент этот объект сериализуется и отправляется на другой сервер, т.е. получается, что
**сервер_1** имеет объект `A'` и **сервер_2** также имеет объект `A'`

потом происходит обновление объекта `A'` на **сервере_1**, т.е. стал `A''`.

Полностью его передавать на **сервер_2** накладно. Оптимально было бы получить `dA = A'' - A'` и передать эту дельту, а затем на **сервере_2** применить `dA` к `A'`, в результате чего получим `A''`

Примерная структура объекта (в реальности объект несколько сложнее):

```
class Outer {
    SimpleObj val1;
    List<ComplexObj> list;
    Map<String, Map<String, List<OtherComplexObj>> map;
}
```

Разность состояния объектов пробую получать с помощью следующих библиотек:

- [java-object-diff](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff)
- [javers](https://github.com/javers/javers)

После получения разности возникает вопрос. Как применить полученный результат на **сервере_2**? Может существуют другие библиотеки, которые бы позволили решить данную задачу?

EDIT: Есть библиотека [spring-synk](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/22/introducing-spring-sync). Из описания как раз следует, что она преследует те же цели, что и в моем случае. На данном этапе она еще в разработке. При попытке использовать ее - StackOverflowError, что есть проблема сложности моего объекта, однако упростить его пока нельзя. Подкручивание параметров jvm не спасает. Поэтому в настоящий момент хочется понять, возможно ли как-то заставить эту библиотеку работать с большими объектам.

Comment: Может, сериализовать в JSON и попробовать что-то типа этого? https://github.com/fge/json-patch

Comment: Может в вашем случае лучше будет реализовать команды для модификации объекта и передавать команды, к команде прикреплять сериализованый объект который добавился, удалился, изменился. Если не хотите гонять маленькие куски собирайте в набор команд и передавайте в тот момент когда бы вы отправили "разницу". И такой нюанс, вы когда на **сервере_2** получите вашу "разницу", то вам придется сделать сериализацию накатить изменения и сделать десериализацию, думаю это тоже затратно если реально объект большой.